# Docker - How to test if a service is running during image creation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm pretty green regarding docker and find myself facing the following problem:

I'm trying to create a dockerfile to generate an image with my companie  software on it. During the installation of that software the install process check if ssh is running with the following command:

```
if [ $(pgrep sshd | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
```

I probably need to precise that I'm installing and starting open-ssh during that same process.

Can you at all check that a service is running during the image creation ?

I cannot ignore that step has it is executed as part of a self extracting mechanism.

Any clue toward the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. When you say "image creation" what do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to run open-ssh inside the container or on the host where you are running the container?

Comment: @Griffin for me the image creation process is when you use your dockerfile to generate an image (docker build [OPTIONS] PATH).

Comment: @yamenk no I want to run open-ssh in the container. But the process that test if the ssh service is up, do so during the docker build process.

Comment: And what is the end goal? If ssh was running then?

Comment: @Griffin then we execute the rest of the auto installer. It's just one of many requirements being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image cannot run services. You are just creating all the necessary things  needed for your container to run, like installing databases, servers, or copying some config files etc in the Dockerfile. The last step in the Dockerfile is where you can give instructions on what to do when you issue a `docker run` command. A script or command can be specified using CMD or ENTRYPOINT in the Dockerfile.

To answer your question, during the image creation process, you cannot check whether a service is running or not. When the container is started, docker will execute the script or command that you can specify in the CMD or ENTRYPOINT. You can use that script to check if your services are running or not and take necessary action after that.

Comment: I was afraid of that. So the only way for me to have an image with our software installed would be to : -First installed all required lib and softwares in the dockerfile. -Two set our autoinstaller as the entrypoint. -Three do a save of the container once all previoous steps are done ?

Comment: @Driky Do you need to run the autoinstaller everytime a container is created out of the image ?

Comment: yes, since I can't run it as part of the docker build process, I will have to run it each time a container is created which is not ideal.

Comment: @Driky Then you don't need the third step. The autoinstaller script should be set as ENTRYPOINT followed by another command which runs forever (so that the container wont stop). See this for example, https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker/blob/master/start.sh   , there is a wait at the very end which will keep the container running until its stopped. 
There is a difference between creating a new container and start/stop an existing container. I think you meant running the autoinstaller script everytime while creating a new container & not when start/stop an existing container.

Comment: yes that is exactly what I meant. Once the software is installed I do not need to run the installer again on the same container.

Comment: @Driky Great, so then following the Dockerfile and start.sh in this project is your way to proceed https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run services during image creation. All processes are killed once a RUN command completes. A service will not keep running between RUN commands. However, each RUN command can start services and use them.

If an image creation command needs a service, start the service and then run the command that depends on the service, all in one RUN command.

```
RUN sudo service ssh start \
    && ssh localhost echo ok \
    && ./install
```

- The first line starts the ssh server and succeeds with the server running.
- The second line tests if the ssh server is up.
- The third line is a placeholder: the 'install' command can use the localhost ssh server.

In case the service fails to start, the `docker build` command will fail.